# Creating a table with a couple as primary key in MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have 2 tables:

1. Authors(id, name, add, DOB) where the fields are INTEGER, CHAR(20), CHAR(20), DATE respectively. Primary key = id.
2. Books(bid, title, publisher) where the fields are INTEGER, CHAR(20), CHAR(20) respectively. Primary key = bid.

I want to create another table Write with fields aid, bid, datePublished, where:

1. aid = INTEGER ... this is actually the id from Authors.
2. bid = INTEGER ... this is actually the bid from Books
3. Primary Key = (aid, bid).

How do I do this?

I tried the following lines of code, and all of them gave syntax errors:

```
CREATE TABLE Write (
    aid INTEGER, 
    bid INTEGER, datePublished DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (aid,bid), 
    FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES Authors(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES Books(bid)
);

CREATE TABLE Write (
    aid INTEGER, 
    bid INTEGER, 
    datePublished DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (aid,bid)
);
```

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

Funny problem you're having. The reason is that `Write` is a reserved keyword in mysql and you can only use it as an identifier if you suround it by backticks in your queries. I recomend you picking another name or, if you really want to use `Write`, replace your create query with

```
CREATE TABLE `Write` (
    aid INTEGER, 
    bid INTEGER, 
    datePublished DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (aid,bid)
);
```

Just remember that any other query on the table `Write` would require the backticks as well, which might lead to annoying errors if someone forgets them.

Comment: Thanks Eric. You were correct. I'll use Writes to make my life easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Write is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), no table can be named that (it *can* using back tics but to make your life easy stay away from names that requires back tics).

Here is the complete schema 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfe22/1

Comment: this is wrong, see my answer and this sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2ecd

Comment: You are correct. It is possible with back ticks. Personally I treat that as a bad hack and never use names that requires back tics.

Comment: +1 for "stay away from backticks"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE Write (aid INTEGER, bid INTEGER, datePublished DATE PRIMARY KEY (aid,bid));
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Amrish. Unfortunately, that too didn't work. I tried what you suggested, and also what you suggested except that I added a comma after DATE and before PRIMARY KEY. Neither worked.

Comment: I'm getting a SQL Syntax error :(

Comment: Do u have created Authors and Books table ? can you please send that also ?